# Can I travel to Svalbard and back from Norway on a Dutch Identity card?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, norway, dutch-citizens

I'm traveling to Svalbard from the UK via Norway in a couple of weeks and would like to travel on my Dutch identity card. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you please tell us your flight number from Oslo to Svalbard, so I can advise whether it stops at Tromsö or is non-stop, as again, that determines where to go on Arrival in Oslo?

Comment: I'm flying Norwegian, one flight is London to Oslo, the other Oslo to Longyearbyen.

Comment: Edited accordingly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Norwegian travel document requirements apply to the whole country, not just the mainland, even though border checks take place between the mainland and Svalbard. **So yes, a Dutch ID card is sufficient**

Upon arrival in Oslo, you will clear mainland Norwegian immigration. There are two different sets of immigration booths for entering and transit passengers. If your tickets are separate **and** you have checked luggage, clear entry immigration to pick it up and re-check it. Otherwise clear transit immigration (signposted "Transfer to non-Schengen destinations").

If having cleared entry immigration, you will also clear exit immigration to reach the gate.

Svalbard, however, only sporadically performs border checks

Comment: I did go through the Schengen exit check in Oslo but I don't recall any Svalbard immigration.

Comment: @Relaxed What year was this?

Comment: 2017, last January in other words. It's also possible I just forgot but I do have a very clear recollection of the Schengen exit check.

Comment: @Relaxed Gonna call the airport tomorrow and ask (not that it's awfully relevant for the initial question but still)